# AmCharts not loading images / SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, vue.js, amcharts

So i stumbled over `AmCharts`, a tool for making charts and graphs, but the thing is, I'm not sure how to make them work together well with `webpack`.

The problem I have is that `AmCharts` can't find their own SVG images inside the `node_module`.

## Example:

[image]

## Chart init and settings:

[image]

It should be said, I'm using Vue.JS with Webpack.
I'm importing amcharts.js and serial.js in the main.js script so I can use these charts over the whole website, but am I forgetting to import something else maybe or is it webpack that is messing with me maybe?
I am able to load seperate SVG files just out from assets, but I can't seem to get AmCharts to load their own SVG files inside their library, which should automatically be done, they are trying but I get a 404 error when loading the chart.

Talked to both Webpack support and AmChart support, but they just pushed this problem to other people. So ended up publishing this question here.

Should also be mentioned that I tried mapping to the images using the option in AmCharts so it would find the files, I even tried copying all the images out of the node_modules amcharts folder into my assets and pointing to the new folder, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated though, thanks!

Best regards
Tobias

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart) page, in `path`/`pathToImages`  property

Comment: This has nothing to do with vue or webpack. I will edit the title.

Answer (score 4):

By default amCharts tries to look for their images in the same directory as the amcharts.js. If you are importing those includes some other way than via `<script>` tag it might fail at that.

To fix that, you will need to set [`path`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#path) property to point where the amCharts' install is manually. I.e.:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "path": "/libs/amcharts/",
  // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can set a global `AmCharts_path` variable to point to the path where amCharts' files reside. I.e.:

```
var AmCharts_path = "/libs/amcharts/";
```

P.S. you don't need to specify full path to /images/ directory. It will assume it's under main amCharts dir.

Comment: Did try this, without any luck, I think webpack might be compressing the files I import to a single js file and making it hard for amCharts to find them.

I did try to copy all the images and then using "pathToImages" directly to my assets, but no luck there either.

Comment: Can you check you browser's console to see exactly what the chart is trying (and failing) to load? Then make sure those files are there in that path.

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue happened to me while working with rails and JS Amcharts.

`amcharts` looks for the images as set by the path 
`this.pathToImages` variable inside `amcharts.js`.

1- Update its value to `this.pathToImages="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/"` and local images won't be required anymore.

Found this here: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar#example

2- Another work around can be updating image path by jQuery. e.g. For scrollbar image you can do
`$("#chart_div > div > div > svg > g:nth-child(12) > g:nth-child(2) > g:nth-child(7) > image").attr('xlink:href', '/path/to/image')`

Hope that helps.